# Fancybox 2 vertical scroll issue

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use the Alt to add extra text in the fancyBox v2.1.4 popup, but the problem is there isn't showing up a vertical scrollbar for the description text, so some of the text cannot be read.

HTML:

```
<!-- Item Project Name -->
                        <li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                            <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                            <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/full/image-01-full.jpg">
                                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                            </a>
                            <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                            <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-01.jpg" alt="IF I PUT TOO MUCH TEXT OVER HERE THERE IS NO SCROLLBAR INSIDE THE POPUP">
                        </li>
                        <!-- End Item Project -->
```

Strange enough, at the fancybox css, all seems right:

`.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}`

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the code you use to initialize fancybox?

Comment: i use Jquery to control it on "onUpdate" event.
exp.
onUpdate : function (){
 let popup = $('.fancybox-opened');
 popup.css("overflow-y", "scroll");
 popup.css("height", "80%");
}

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CSS for setting up scroll issues. You can hide scrollbar with the help of "helpers"

Try following code to fix scroll issue.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView   : false,
    height      : 'auto',
    autoSize    : false,
    helpers : {
          overlay : {
              locked: false
          }
    }
});
```